# Diagonalisation of equations for NDSolve

Tags: differential-equations, matrix, interpolation

I have a linear matrix differential equation and I wish to speed up evaluation by diagonalising using eigenvectors. There is an example in Help for finite elements under "swinging beam" that is desperately in need of this. The basic equation I am trying to solve is

[image: Mathematica graphics]

where ***M*** is a mass matrix, ***K*** is a stiffness matrix and ***f*** is a vector of forces (possibly time dependent). I can make progress with diagonalising the system but am having difficulty putting it back together. I would also like to speed up my solution method.

I start with a helper function to make random mass and stiffness matrices that are symmetric positive definite.

```
ClearAll[symetricPD];
symetricPD::usage = 
  "symetricPD[n,{a,b}] gives a positive definite matrix that is \
symmetric of size n by n. The values {a,b}  a<b shape the typical \
magnitude and dynamic range of the elements.";
symetricPD[n_, {a_?Positive, b_?Positive}] := Module[{d, t, m1},
  d = RandomReal[{a, b}, n];
  t = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {n, n}];
  m1 = Transpose[t].DiagonalMatrix[d].t;
  m1]
```

As an example I start with 5 degrees of freedom, zero initial conditions and a constant force on one equation.

```
SeedRandom[112233]
nn = 5;
m = symetricPD[nn, {1, 10}];
k = symetricPD[nn, {1, 100}];
f = Join[ConstantArray[0, nn - 1], {1}];
icu = ConstantArray[0, nn]; 
icu1 = ConstantArray[0, nn];
```

This can be solved easily although it gives an error which I hope is unimportant

```
sol = NDSolveValue[{m .u''[t] + k. u[t] == f, u[0] == icu, 
    u'[0] == icu1}, u, {t, 0, 10}];
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Plotting the results is fine

```
Column[Table[Plot[sol[t][[n]], {t, 0, 10}], {n, nn}]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Now we set up the diagonal version starting with an eigenvalue decomposition and transform the mass and stiffness matrices to diagonal matrices. We also have to transform the initial conditions and force vector. I then solve. Is this the best way to solve?

```
{vals, vecsR} = Eigensystem[{k, m}];
vecsC = Transpose[vecsR];
md = Diagonal[vecsR.m.vecsC];
kd = Diagonal[vecsR.k.vecsC];
fd = vecsR.f;
icud = vecsR.icu;
icu1d = vecsR.icu1;
sold = Table[
   NDSolveValue[{md[[n]] u''[t] + kd[[n]] u[t] == fd[[n]], 
     u[0] == icud[[n]], u'[0] == icu1d[[n]]}, u, {t, 0, 10}],
   {n, nn}];
```

I now have to transform the solution back to the original space. One of the problems is that the time steps in each solve are different so I can't get the coordinates out of the interpolation functions transform them back and re-interpolate.  Is there a better way than this?

```
res[t_] := Evaluate[vecsC.(#[t] & /@ sold)]

Column[Table[Plot[res[t][[n]], {t, 0, 10}], {n, nn}]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

I am now interested in timing so I increase the size of the problem

```
nn = 50;
m = symetricPD[nn, {1, 10}];
k = symetricPD[nn, {1, 100}];
f = Join[ConstantArray[0, nn - 1], {1}];
icu = ConstantArray[0, nn];
icu1 = ConstantArray[0, nn];

Timing[
 sol = NDSolveValue[{m .u''[t] + k. u[t] == f, u[0] == icu, 
     u'[0] == icu1}, u, {t, 0, 10}];
 ]

(* {7.23845, Null} *)
```

Now for the transformed version

```
Timing[
 {vals, vecsR} = Eigensystem[{k, m}];
 vecsC = Transpose[vecsR];
 md = Diagonal[vecsR.m.vecsC];
 kd = Diagonal[vecsR.k.vecsC];
 fd = vecsR.f;
 icud = vecsR.icu;
 icu1d = vecsR.icu1;
 sold = Table[
   NDSolveValue[{md[[n]] u''[t] + kd[[n]] u[t] == fd[[n]], 
     u[0] == icud[[n]], u'[0] == icu1d[[n]]}, u, {t, 0, 10}],
   {n, nn}];
 ]

(* {1.48201, Null} *)
```

Which is a lot better. Could it be better still?

```
res[t_] := Evaluate[vecsC.(#[t] & /@ sold)]
```

Plotting gives the same results so the method is working but the time to plot the diagonal method is very poor so my method for transforming back is a disaster.

```
Plot[sol[t][[1]], {t, 0, 10}, PlotLabel -> "Brute force solution"]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
Plot[res[t][[1]], {t, 0, 10}, PlotLabel -> "Diagonal solution"]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Check that the mass matrix has been diagonalized successfully.

```
MatrixPlot[vecsR.m.vecsC // Chop]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Any ideas on how to transform back with the interpolation functions. Also, is my method of solving the best? Can we solve all the diagonal equations simultaneously thus getting the same time steps?
Thanks

Comment: I am not an expert, but maybe you could optimise this line `res[t_] := Evaluate[vecsC.(#[t] & /@ sold)]`: I'm not sure if `Evaluate` is needed and if `:=` is better than `=` in this case. I haven't tried but I would guess that's where you loose efficiency. Apart from this, you could perhaps gain more speed in the first part by choosing random diagonal (positive definite) matrices and a random invertible matrice (for the change of basis) rather than diagonalizing your random matrices $m$ and $k$. This is to avoid using `Eigensystem`.

Comment: @anderstood Yes I agree that something is wrong with `res[t_]` and it could be done better. I am stuck with the random matrices because the physical matrices they model can be anything. `Eigensystem` is standard here.

Comment: I gained a factor 8 by removing `Evaluate` in `res` (for $n=10$). Note that you made a typo with `icud` and `icdu`.

Comment: @anderstood Thanks progress. Corrected the typo.

Comment: Very interesting question. Here are a few thoughts: `Method -> {"EquationSimplification" -> "Residual"}` make the message go away. `NDSolve` the goes to use `"TimeIntegration" -> "IDA"` have look in the docu, perhaps there are some useful options for this problem. For comparison it might be better to plot the difference: `Plot[res[t][[n]] - sol[t][[n]], {t, 0, 10}]`. One other thing that's a bit inconvenient, is that timings (`AbsoluteTiming` is better than `Timing`) vary a lot from run to run. Do you have a real example. In the FEMProgramming tutorial there is a sect. on model order reduction

Comment: That MOR section has a suggestion for mapping back but this approach is for a first order system. You could transform the second order system to a coupled system of first order. See [here](http://modelreduction.com/) for resources on second order systems MOR. Another idea might be to use only the, say, 10 smallest eigenvalues. If you figure this out I'd be very interested to see the result.

Comment: @user21 Thanks for the hints. I could change to a first order system. The matrices are then 2n by 2n before the eigenvalue problem. Will the eigensolver take the large order?  The classic approach used to be Guyan reduction with some approximation for the mass matrix. A key point is sorting out the interpolation function so that I can use it like Mathematica does for the swinging beam.  I will continue to work on improvements.

Comment: @Hugh, `Eigensystem` is expensive to compute. If you look at the `MOR` code in the FEM tutorial you'll see that that uses `LinearSolve` - you may get away with this. But I don't know. It might be worth a shot though. Good luck!

Comment: Here is something that's a bit quicker: `res[t_] := vecsC.Developer\`ToPackedArray[Through[sold[t]]]`

Comment: @user21 Thanks for that tip.

Comment: It's in the [FEMProgramming tutorial](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/FEMDocumentation/tutorial/FiniteElementProgramming.html), search for Model Order Reduction in the transient section.